# Regex Pattern working in regex tester but not in actual code

Tags: javascript, regex, email-validation

The following regex check is not working in the code. But if i use this pattern at regex101.com it works perfectly

```js
var pattern = "^([a-zA-Z0-9]([-\.\w]*[a-zA-Z0-9])*@([a-zA-Z0-9][-\w]*[a-zA-Z0-9]\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,9})$";
var value = "test@user.com";

var regexp = new RegExp(pattern);
if (!regexp.test(value)) {
   alert("Failed");
} else {
 alert("passed");
}
```

Could you please help me why this is happening here. By the way if i make some modifications like given below, it works. But i want it to work with (new RegExp(pattern))

```js
var pattern = /^([a-zA-Z0-9]([-\.\w]*[a-zA-Z0-9])*@([a-zA-Z0-9][-\w]*[a-zA-Z0-9]\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,9})$/;
var value = "test@user.com";

if (!pattern.test(value)) {
   alert("Failed");
} else {
 alert("passed");
}
```

Comment: *But i want it to work with (new RegExp(pattern)* Why?

Comment: @torazaburo got the answer.. I need to add extra backslash in regular expression infront of each backslash. because "new regExp(pattern)" was stripping backslashes from the pattern and thats why it was not working.

Answer (score 3):

Just remove the double quotes and put your Regex simply in forward slashes.

```js
var pattern = /^([a-zA-Z0-9]([-\.\w]*[a-zA-Z0-9])*@([a-zA-Z0-9][-\w]*[a-zA-Z0-9]\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,9})$/;
var value = "test@user.com";

var regexp = new RegExp(pattern);
if (!regexp.test(value)) {
   alert("Failed");
} else {
 alert("passed");
}
```

It's because, if you're putting double quotes, then you need to escape your regular expression

However, you can simply put your regular expression as it is when placing it between forward slashes.

Comment: But if we have to do it with a quote ?as in actual code this regex is coming from a json object.

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape those backslashes (`\`).

```js
var pattern = "^([a-zA-Z0-9]([-\\.\\w]*[a-zA-Z0-9])*@([a-zA-Z0-9][-\\w]*[a-zA-Z0-9]\\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,9})$";
var value = "test@user.com";

var regexp = new RegExp(pattern);
if (!regexp.test(value)) {
   console.log("Failed");
} else {
 console.log("passed");
}
```

Comment: @torazaburo He need **explanation** why it is not working with `RegExp`.

Comment: @torazaburo from the question: "But i want it to work with (new RegExp(pattern))"

Comment: @torazaburo OP Said: *why this is happening here*. Clearly he wanted an **explanation**